# transferring a variable through different web pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I'm building a plug-in for wordpress, where I have a couple of webpages with tables, filled with data from a database. Right now I'm working on the part where I click on a number (MemberID) which should redirect to a page, having all the information from another table regarding this number. I've tried transfering the data through the URL, with both

```
    ?MemberID=".$item->MemberID."
```

and

```
    /MemberID="$item->MemberID."
```

, but everytime I try to alter the URL, the webpages suddenly can't seem to find itself anymore. I'm sure it has to do whith this part of the code:

```
    add_submenu_page( null    , 'Manage memberDetails'  , 'memberDetails'   , 'manage_options', 'memberDetails'       , 'memberDetails_list'   );
```

where the fifth value sets the URL for this page to be

```
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=memberDetails
```

So whenever I try to add something behind that URL, it doesn't acknowledge the existance of said page anymore, resulting in a redirection error.

Is there a way to transfer the variable without using the URL, or is there a way to give more of a dynamic to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed my fairly basic mistake out this is what went wrong:

The URL is

```
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=memberDetails
```

where I tried to turn it into

```
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=memberDetails/memberID=
```

which creates a whole new webpage and is therefor impossible in this case. I need to transfer the variable behind the memberID=, not refer to a whole new webpage. The other thing I tried to do was

```
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=memberDetails?memberID=
```

which is impossible, because the second ? in the URL needed to be replaced with a &
From there on, it was pretty easy to use $_GET to retrieve the variable from the URL and use it.

So for extra clarity, this is how the URL is supposed to look

```
    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=memberDetails&memberID=
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using add_submenu_page wrong. The first param is required and can not be null.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

You need to get that fixed first so you page properly works.

Comment: the first param is required if you want it to show up in the plug-in menu. I left it null purposely, because I want it to be only accesable through other pages, because it NEEDS a memberID value to function. As far as I've tested it, leaving it null or adding it into the menu hasn't made a difference for me.

Comment: " Use NULL or set to 'options.php' if you want to create a page that doesn't appear in any menu (see example below). "  It even sais this in your own link...

Comment: Ok, if that works for you. But how do you know what page ULR to pass the value to? Secondly, if it requires a memberID to function, check for it and give an error if it does not exit. You are going to need to sanitize that value coming in anyway.

Comment: The problem is not with the memberID not being transfered, the problem is with the webpage not being found when I edited the URL. The why was pretty simple because I'm a coding noob. I'll answer my own question in a minute :)